# Kaspersky warning everytime I open IE8 or open a tab in IE8

Tags: anti-virus, internet-explorer-8, kaspersky

I am running Kaspersky Internet Security 7.0.1.325

I keep getting a warning saying "Proactive Defense", "Attempt to run browser with command line parameters..."

I am just opening IE8. There is a default webpage (google.com) other than that nothing else. This also happens if I open a file (say a .xps) that opens by default in IE.

I don't want to shut of my proactive defense, but I've tried the option "Add to Trusted zone" but it doesn't make a difference to my User Experience.

This does not occur with either FFX or Chrome.

Any idea's on how to stop Kaspersky from stopping IE?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have a virus that has changed the file association or the Open verb for IE so that it tries to open at a specific site. Have you tried running a virus scan? And using multiple tools such as [MalwareBytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/)?